# Update from checkbox to wrong ID in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

issue for days now.

I have a form with multiple checkboxes, I will never know how many rows will be in the form, and I am aware that an empty checkbox will not post to the processing page. I have also tried providing a hidden value to the checkbox to no avail...

I know there is a straightforward method to this, please assist:

The following code is on the form:

```
echo "<td><center><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='jce_pnt_id[]' value='$jce_pnt_id' onclick='return false;' /><br>$jce_pnt_id</center></td>";

echo "<td title='Task Complete ?'><center><input type='hidden' name='tr_g[]' value='25'>";
              if($jce_ins_complete < '100' || $jce_ins_act_complete == '0')
                  {
                      echo "<input type='checkbox' name='tr_g[]' id='$jce_pnt_id' value='100'>";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      echo "<input type='checkbox' name='tr_g[]' id='$jce_pnt_id' value='100' checked='checked'>";
                  }
          echo "</center></td>";
```

Here is a screenshot (look at the red circled column):

[image: output]

Here is the processing snippet (not working):

```
$jce_pnt_id = $_POST['jce_pnt_id'];
$tr_g = $_POST['tr_g']; // jce_pnt_act_complete

foreach ($tr_g as $id => $trg) {
//if(empty($trg)) { $trg = "0"; }
 $queryg = "UPDATE `jce_pnt` SET `jce_pnt_act_complete` = '$trg' WHERE `jce_pnt_id` = '$jce_pnt_id[$id]'";
 $resultg = mysqli_query($cxn,$queryg);
```

}

*** The value writes to the wrong ID in the database.**

Comment: Suggestion:`echo "<input type='checkbox' name='tr_g[]' id='$jce_pnt_id' value='100'".($jce_ins_complete < 100?"":"checked='checked'").">";` 0 is also <100

Comment: Thanx @mplungjan that's a great idea will implement now.

Comment: Hi @mplungjan this solved the problem for me, thank you.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question. It is very localised to you